# Confusion about when NumPy array slices are references and when they are copies

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

If I try the following:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.arange(10)
>>> s = arr[2:5]
>>> s[:] = 12
>>> s, arr
(array([12, 12, 12]), array([ 0,  1, 12, 12, 12,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9]))
>>> s = s // 2
>>> s, arr
(array([6., 6., 6.]), array([ 0,  1, 12, 12, 12,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9]))
```

It seems that the first time around `s` is just a reference to part of `arr`, so modifying it also changes the array (some `12`s appear in `arr`); but the second time around, `s` has become a copy of that part of the array, and `arr` is not affected (the `12`s in `arr` do not become `6`).

Why does this happen? What makes `s = s // 2` different?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Slicing a Numpy array always returns a view (reference) of an array.  Modifying the slice will modify the original array.

In your second example you re-assign to the name `s`.  That does not modify the object.  A **new** array is created to represent the result of `s // 2` - which has **no relationship to** the original `arr` - and then `s` becomes a name for that new array.

To modify `s` in-place, use an augmented assignment operator, such as `//=`, or (as you have already seen) slice assignment such as with `[:]`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.arange(10)
>>> s = arr[2:5]
>>> s, arr
(array([2, 3, 4]), array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]))
>>> s[:] = 12 # modifies the slice, and therefore the original
>>> s, arr
(array([12, 12, 12]), array([ 0,  1, 12, 12, 12,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9]))
>>> s //= 2 # modifies the slice, and therefore the original
>>> s, arr
(array([6, 6, 6]), array([0, 1, 6, 6, 6, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]))
>>> s = s // 2 # makes a new slice (and reassigns the name), so the original is untouched
>>> s, arr
(array([3, 3, 3]), array([0, 1, 6, 6, 6, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]))
```

Comment: This is not clear enough - your first sentence implies that there's a "slice object" you use as index. This would be `2:5` here. Then you state that you assign to this "slice object" but it does not modify "the object". Please make a clearer distinction between the *variable* called `slice` and what objects you actually mean, because what you want to say is that in the second example the original array `arr` does not change.

Comment: @Christoph90 feel free to suggest edits or write an answer of your own.  Since it was accepted by the original asker I don't see any reason to change it.

Comment: I agree with @Christoph . The point `slice = slice / 2` is an assignation, while `slice[:] = slice / 2` isn't, has been shown, the **reasons why** are not clear, though it is exactly the question asked:"*What makes `slice = slice / 2` different*". I can avoid writing wrong code, but I don't have a clear understanding (as they say: *If you give a man a fish, he will be hungry tomorrow. If you teach a man to fish, he will be richer forever* [cit.](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_a_man_a_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_day;_teach_a_man_to_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_lifetime)).

Comment: The reason why is that the language defines it that way, by convention. It could have been done differently, but that was the behavior a numpy developer felt was reasonable.

Comment: @Christoph90 I fixed the issues. The problem is that "slice" meant three different things: a slice of a Numpy array created by slicing it; an instance of the built-in Python `slice` type (which gets created implicitly by the slicing syntax); and OP's original variable name `slice` (which should not be used, because it shadows the type name).

Comment: @mins it is for **the same reason as with any other type**. Writing `x // 2` is expected to create a new object (although this can be optimized away **for immutable types only**), not to modify the existing object named by `x` in-place. Writing `x //= 2` **may** modify the `x` object in-place; it is semantically equivalent to `x = x // 2` **for the name `x` itself**, but may effect the rest of the program state due to aliasing (in Numpy, this kind of aliasing is very deliberate).

Answer (score 2):

Use `[:]` to assign the values back:

```
>>> arr = np.arange(10)
>>> s = arr[2:5]
>>> s[:] = 12
>>> print(arr)
[ 0  1 12 12 12  5  6  7  8  9]
>>> s[:] = s // 2
>>> print(arr)
[0 1 6 6 6 5 6 7 8 9]
```