# prettytable is updating all rows in the table

Tags: python, numpy

I am facing a difficulty with a package for building beautiful tables. I would like `gradJ` to be updated in parts, just like the term `i`.

I would like to see this:

```
  +---+---------------------+
  | i |        GradJ        |
  +---+---------------------+
  | 0 | [1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.] |
  | 1 | [1. 2. 0. 0. 0. 0.] |
  | 2 | [1. 2. 3. 0. 0. 0.] |
  | 3 | [1. 2. 3. 4. 0. 0.] |
  | 4 | [1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 0.] |
  | 5 | [1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6.] |
  +---+---------------------+
```

However, my code returns this:

```
  +---+---------------------+
  | i |        GradJ        |
  +---+---------------------+
  | 0 | [1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6.] |
  | 1 | [1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6.] |
  | 2 | [1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6.] |
  | 3 | [1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6.] |
  | 4 | [1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6.] |
  | 5 | [1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6.] |
  +---+---------------------+
```

I simplified the code that is causing the problem.

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable
import numpy

myTable = PrettyTable(["i", "GradJ"])
gradJ = numpy.zeros(6)
for i in range(6):
    gradJ[i] = i+1
    myTable.add_row([i, gradJ[:]])
print(myTable)
```

I have read the PrettyTable documentation, but I still can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Confusion about when NumPy array slices are references and when they are copies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53156714/confusion-about-when-numpy-array-slices-are-references-and-when-they-are-copies)

Comment: It look like the `gradJ` is the same reference for all six rows. You will need to make a copy of it, prior to adding the row.

Comment: Better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60868296/in-numpy-q1-p-instead-of-q1-p-yet-p-is-modified-when-i-modify-q1

Comment: `[:]` makes a copy of Python lists, but not of NumPy arrays.

Comment: Thank you to all the answers, they helped me a lot. In fact, I did not know about this question of copy. I am used to Fortran90 and Matlab, so I am making basic mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a NumPy array is not a standard `list`, calling `[:]` will not properly create a copy.

Here is the correct usage using `numpy.ndarray.copy`:

```py
from prettytable import PrettyTable
import numpy

myTable = PrettyTable(["i", "GradJ"])
gradJ = numpy.zeros(6)
for i in range(6):
    gradJ[i] = i+1
    myTable.add_row([i, gradJ.copy()]) # Use numpy.ndarray.copy
print(myTable)
```

---

Here is a modified version that removes the dependency on `PrettyTable` and demonstrates NumPy's `copy()` method.

```py
import numpy

size, rows = 6, []

# Populate the table
row = numpy.zeros(size)
for i in range(size):
    row[i] = i + 1 # Fill in the corresponding column
    rows.append([i, row.copy()]) # Call .copy(), not [:]

# Display the table
for row in rows:
    print(row)
```

Output:

```
[0, array([1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])]
[1, array([1., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0.])]
[2, array([1., 2., 3., 0., 0., 0.])]
[3, array([1., 2., 3., 4., 0., 0.])]
[4, array([1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 0.])]
[5, array([1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6.])]
```